# Are argv[1]-[x] (command line arguments) just treated as regular variables when writing code?

Tags: python

For a project we are supposed to filter twitter data out by keywords entered through the command line. I've had basically no exposure to this so I'm reeling together to figure it out.

If I enter 'trump' into the command line, and have an if statement like:

```
if argv[1] in tweet:
    counter+=1
```

Will that work?

The reason I can't try this myself is because I also don't know how to get to running a program through the command line. The internet told me:

```
$ python filename.py
```

Would be sufficient in running from the command line, but I'm getting nothing but errors, even after bringing the terminal to inside the project file where the python file is.

Comment: You can use argv like that if you've imported it from sys. Make sure you do a check on the length of argv before doing anything with it. For example, in your case if you ran the program like that without any argument after "filename.py", you would get an Index (out of range) error.

Comment: Ok, do you have any comments for why "python filename.py" does not run the program when entered in the terminal?

Comment: @grilam14 What exactly do you see whan you attempt to run the program? What is the error message?

Comment: I enter python trends.py and get "NameError: name 'trends' is not defined"

Comment: @grilam14 Is that all? Looks like a Python error to me. What exactly is in the `.py` file?

Comment: I edited the error. I know that trends.py exists because it is in my documents folder. That is all I enter when opening terminal.

Comment: Do you use variable `trends` in you script? Has it been defined? Anyway, the error you get is a Python error in the file that you are trying to execute. It has nothing to do with the command line.

Comment: I fixed it. I had to start with cd documents cd twitter then "python trends.py"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `sys.argv` is a list of strings which represent all command line parameters. In particular, `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the Python script. Note that you must `import sys` first.